# Indy TCPServer/Client TLS

Tags: c++, c++builder, openssl, indy

Пишу приложение на *C++Builder XE8*, Использую компоненты *Indy TCPServer* и *TCPClient*, поскольку среда передачи будет опасной то необходима шифрование, выбрал протокол *TLS 1.2* и разместил компоненты `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` и `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` на сервере и клиенте соответственно. Установил сертификаты:

```
IOHandler1->SSLOptions->RootCertFile = "C:\\root.pem";
IOHandler1->SSLOptions->CertFile = "C:\\server.pem";
IOHandler1->SSLOptions->KeyFile = "C:\\server.key";
IOHandler1->SSLOptions->DHParamsFile = "C:\\dh1024.pem";
TCPServer1->Active = true;
Mode = sslmUnassigned
```

Для клиента аналогично со своими сертификатами. С `CipherList` поиграл, ставил параметры для *TLS 1.2* с ключем *DH*, *DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256*. Клиент ни в какую не подключается. Файрвол отключен, и без шифрования работает. После долгого зависания клиент выдает *Socket Error #2* Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit, приложение пишется под windows 64bit.

Comment: а dll файлы скопировали с проектом? что бы ssl работал dll ки должны тоже совподать

Comment: ssleay32.lib и libeay32.lib? Нет, а нужно ли их как то подключать? или просто закинуть в папку с проектом?

Comment: да эти, самое простое закинуть в папку с exe файлом. там кажется 3 dll ки были.

Comment: пока не помогает. Библиотеки взял с Openssl установленного на этой системе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Server1Connect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
 if(AContext->Connection->IOHandler->InheritsFrom(__classid(TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase)))
  {
    ((TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase *)AContext->Connection->IOHandler)->PassThrough = false;
  }
}
```

Вот ответ